# Functions for C# dynamic item

Tags: c#, function

I wonder whether it is possible to create functions for dynamic items (textboxes, buttons) like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and other?

If yes, then how?

- I know you can use `DynamicalButton.Click();` but that doesn't help much.

**EDIT**

As example, you can make a function like `Button_Click` or `TextBox_TextChanged`, `PictureBox_MouseOver` easily when you make the objects with designer and they work properly. How to do that with dynamic objects?

Comment: Edited, check after **EDIT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the answer**

```
DynamicalObject.Click += new EventHandler(DynamicalObject_Click);
protected void DynamicalObject_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  what happens on the event
}
```

as example